# polymorphic dispatch: distinguishing Python integers vs. floating-point numbers vs. strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, python-2.5

Suppose I have a function that needs to dispatch between one of three other functions, depending on whether it's "integer-like" or "floating-point-like" or "string-like" (or something else):

```
def handleThing(x):
   if is_integer_like(x):
      return handleInteger(x)
   if is_floating_point_like(x):
      return handleFloatingPoint(x)
   if isinstance(x, basestring):
      return handleString(x)
   raise ValueError('handleThing only handles numbers and strings')
```

How can I write `is_integer_like` and `is_floating_point_like` to handle the following types, *without* requiring the use of the `numpy` library? I'm looking for something like duck-typing but am stumped since there doesn't seem to be a common method that would allow me to distinguish them.

When I do the same sort of thing to identify whether something is a mapping type, in addition to `isinstance(x, collections.Mapping)` I typically do something like

```
def ismapping(x):
   return hasattr(x, 'iteritems')
```

I need to handle:

- integer-like types:

  - `int`
  - `long`
  - all `numpy` integer types (`np.int`, `np.int32`, `np.uint32`, etc.)
- floating-point like types:

  - `float`
  - `complex`
  - all `numpy` floating-point types (`np.float32`, `np.float64`, etc.)

---

edit: I'm also curious how to do this in Python 2.5.3 since I'm stuck with that version of Jython.

Comment: Maybe something [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/numbers.html) can fit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution that doesn't rely on classes explicitly `register`ing themselves with the `number` ABCs (so it'll work on old NumPy versions and Python 2.5), you can use [`operator.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.index) to test whether something is supposed to behave as an integer. (This is a wrapper around `__index__`, the thing you implement to make your objects usable as list indices.)

```
def handleThing(x):
    try:
        operator.index(x)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        return handleInteger(x)

    if isinstance(x, basestring):
        return handleString(x)

    try:
        # Would give false positive for strings, but we handled those already.
        float(x)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        return handleFloatingPoint(x)

    # You might want TypeError here.
    raise ValueError('handleThing only handles numbers and strings')
```

Comment: awesome! How does operator.index "know" about numpy integers?

Comment: @JasonS: They implement the [`__index__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/) method.

Comment: oh. duh, got it. Thanks! This really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it implements an appropriate abstract base class:

```
def handleThing(x):
   import numbers
   if isinstance(x, numbers.Integral):
      return handleInteger(x)
   elif isinstance(x, numbers.Real):
      return handleFloatingPoint(x)
   elif isinstance(x, basestring):
      return handleString(x)
   raise ValueError('handleThing only handles numbers and strings')
```

Using python 2.7, and numpy 1.12:

```
>>> all([isinstance(t(1.0), numbers.Integral) for t in (np.int, np.int32, np.uint32, np.int64, numpy.uint64)])
True

>>> all([isinstance(t(1.0), numbers.Real) for t in (float, np.float32, np.float64, np.float128)])
True
```

Note that a `complex` number is **not** a real number, you should test that against `numbers.Complex`.

Comment: `isinstance(np.int32(1), numbers.Integral) -> False`

Comment: oh, nice! I tried looking at the base classes of `np.float64` but somehow all I could find was `object`. Looks like `isinstance(np.float64(123.456), numbers.Real)` returns `True`.

Comment: oh, @MosesKoledoye found a counterexample. drat. :-(

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I cannot reproduce that on Python 3.5

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python 2.7 it is; which is OP's version. Seems to work on Python 3 tho

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I know, but interesting that there is a discrepancy.

Comment: Probably depends on NumPy version. The `numbers` ABCs (and most complex ABCs) can't automatically tell whether a class implements the corresponding concept; they rely on people explicitly calling `numbers.Whatever.register(WhateverElse)`.

Comment: On python 2.7 (as the question is tagged), and the latest numpy (1.12),  `isinstance(np.int32(1), numbers.Integral)` -> True

Comment: Yes, as the docs say, *New in version 2.6.*, so it probably took a bit for the `numpy` developers to fit the `numpy` numeric types into the hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, interesting -- yeah, I'm using numpy 1.11.1 -- gotta try upgrading.

Comment: While this might work on recent NumPy builds, it's not going to be very helpful for any users stuck on releases from before the [patch](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4547) that added the necessary `register` calls.